# React unit testing issue could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I have wrapped the App in provider but its shows wrap the content in provider while testing.Dont know how to achieve it.Is there any other way to achieve this

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer.js';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

const store=createStore(rootReducer,compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))); 


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Login.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Login from './Login' 
 


test("Second test",()=>{ 
    const {getByText} = render( <Login/> );
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Comment: Show the code of the `Login` component.